# Better CoffeeScript syntax for jQuery parameters

Tags: coffeescript

I have this code for making a post request, sending some data, and logging the return value

```
$.post '/saveletter', {start: {x: startX, y:startY}, letter: currentLetter, unitVectors: letter.unitVectorsJson(), timeVectors: letter.timeVectorsJson()}, (data) =>
  console.log data
```

I want to split the long parameter object into several lines, for better readability, but can't figure out the syntax that will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make your code more readable, you can use the following ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2abB/1/) and [compiled result](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3astartX%20=%20startY%20=%20currentLetter%20=%20%27dummy%27;%0Aletter%20=%20unitVectorsJson%3a%20%28-%3E%29,%20timeVectorsJson%3a%20%28-%3E%29%0A%0A%24.post%20%27/saveletter%27,%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%C2%A0start%3a%C2%A0%C2%A0x%3a%20startX,%20y%3a%20startY%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%C2%A0letter%3a%20currentLetter%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%C2%A0unitVectors%3a%20letter.unitVectorsJson%28%29%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%C2%A0timeVectors%3a%20letter.timeVectorsJson%28%29%0A,%20%28data%29%20=%3E%0A%C2%A0%C2%A0console.log%20data%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B)):

```
$.post '/saveletter',
    start:
        x: startX
        y: startY
    letter: currentLetter
    unitVectors: letter.unitVectorsJson()
    timeVectors: letter.timeVectorsJson()
, (data) =>
  console.log data​​
```

In Coffeescript, `{` and `}` may be omitted from the object literal. And commas may be exchanged for newlines (within an object literal, *not* between arguments).

The following is also valid, but might be less readable (ie not obvious at the first glance):

```
start: x: startX, y: startY
```